# AngularJS - Allow a calculated input to be editable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a basic addition calculator that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js">
</script> 
</head>
<body>    
    <input type="number" ng-model="input1" /> + <input type="number" ng-model="input2" /> = <input type="number" ng-model="input1 + input2" />
</body>
</html>
```

Which looks like this:

2 + 3 = 5

I now have a requirement to make the third input editable and when changed it changes the value in the first input so that the numbers add up.  So in the above example, supposing I change 5 to 6 it will look like this:

3 + 3 = 6

But because the model of the third input is a calculation I can't edit it. Please can someone advise how can I make it so that all three inputs are editable and yet still perform the required calculation?

Comment: Logically speaking, assuming strictly addition, on answer change => subtract answer by input 2 => assign result to input 1

Comment: I think `value="{{ input1 + input2 }}"` will work, the `ng-model` is for binding, not interpolating expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to respond to the ng-change event of the inputs on a controller

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js">
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="input1" ng-change="calc()"/> + <input type="number" ng-model="input2" ng-change="calc()"/> = <input type="number" ng-model="result" ng-change="recalc()" />
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

  angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl',function($scope){

    
    $scope.recalc = function(){

      $scope.input1 = $scope.result - $scope.input2;

    };

    $scope.calc = function(){
      $scope.result = $scope.input1 + $scope.input2;
    }

  });

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Just wondering why you still keep ng-value="input1 + input2" ?  Other than that, I like the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach :D

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js">
  </script> 
</head>
 <body>    
  <input type="number" ng-model="input1" ng-change="answ1=input1+input2" /> + 
  <input type="number" ng-model="input2" ng-change="answ1=input1+input2" /> = 
  <input type="number" ng-model="answ1" ng-change="input1=answ1-input2" />
 </body>
</html>
```

When edited any of the boxes it reflect the change...